# MS DOS | Get text input from user

Tags: batch-file, dos, dosbox

I've got to create a batch file that will run with DosBox.
The program should change the color of the text by asking user to enter name of the color.
Here's a code of what I've done so far for you to better understand:

```
@echo off

:start
cls
echo COLOR TEXT
echo.
choice /C12/S/N Choose color of the text (1 - red 2 - yellow)  
if errorlevel 2 goto yellow
if errorlevel 1 goto red


:red
[42;31;40m
cls
echo COLOR TEXT
echo.
choice /C12/S/N Choose color of the text (1 - red 2 - yellow)  
if errorlevel 2 goto yellow
if errorlevel 1 goto red


:yellow
[42;33;40m
cls
echo COLOR TEXT
echo.
choice /C12/S/N Choose color of the text (1 - red 2 - yellow)  
if errorlevel 2 goto yellow
if errorlevel 1 goto red
```

In this program color of text is controlled by pressing keys (1 - for red, 2 - for yellow).
But is there any way to create a program that would control color by user entering name of the color
(e.g. for setting red color user would have to input "red" and press enter, for yellow - "yellow" and so on).

I used command "choice", but it only allows to press keys, not to input text.
I know there's a command "set /p" for batch files, but it doesn't seem to work for MS DOS.

Is there anyone who could help me, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider whether this might be better asked in [retrocomputing.se].

Comment: Unless you're doing something odd, you're using DOSBox's DOS, not MS-DOS, which has no text input commands.  You could use some external utility like [wbat](https://www.horstmuc.de/ui.htm).

Comment: I already found the solution. Here it is if anyone needs it: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/24450/how-can-i-have-the-user-input-a-string-and-then-do-comparisons-on-it-in-a-batch